# Settings Git Tortoise to new credentials

Tags: git, credentials

I have set the credentials to my tortoise settings, but when I push to git alsways the old user/password dialog is shown.
What is wrong ?
Second question : how can I remove system credentials ? With the windows tool it is not possible

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sl0sK.png)

Comment: Have you read the documentation of tortoisegit ? https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-git-credential

Answer (score 0):

First, if TortoiseGit is using the "System" Git, the helper should be "manager-core", not "wincred"

Second, check if you have any password already cached in the Windows Credential Manager with:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential-manager-core get
```

(Assuming you have in your %PATH% `C:\path\to\git\mingw64\libexec\git-core`)

If you do, remove it:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com" | git credential-manager-core erase
```

The next push will pop up a dialog asking you for your (updated) credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows "Credential Manage" to clean out the old.
Easiest way to find this is by typing "credential" into the Start Menu search bar.  Or you can go to ControlPanel-->UserAccounts-->CredentialManager.
Under "Generic Credentials", use the drop-down button to the right of each credential to show details and expose the "Remove from vault" link, which you should use to clean out any old stuff.
Then on your next push, you will be prompted for username/password, which is automatically stored in Credential Manager (under the auspices of the default "wincred" helper.) If you make a mistake, you will have to repeat the process.

Comment: `wincred` is obsolete. And no need to fiddle directly with the Windows Credential Manager: that is what the `git-credential-manager-core.exe` is for.